# Cloth tearing out render view

Tags: modeling, rendering, cloth-simulation

I was working on a female character for a short Animated movie, I was able to manage modeling everything looks great in Blender

[image]

Dress was all fit nicely, where as, as soon as I tried to render it  (using cycles render), cloths behave abnormal and disappeared, randomly and making islands.

[image]

Any ideas why its showing different results?

Comment: Make sure that on any modifiers the viewport setting is the same as the render.

Comment: Thanks, can you please post it as answer? so that I can accept it as correct.

Comment: Ok added it as a answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure that on any modifiers the viewport setting is the same as the render.

Comment: Your solution worked for me, Thank a lot, Have a nice time.